# Perform check on record before performing update with Prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, prisma

I'm creating the backend for a simple app which allows users to create, update, and delete products. Using Express as my framework, with Postgres as my DB and Prisma, which I'm new to, as my ORM. Users and products have a one-to-many relationship. Prisma's documentation states that when updating a record, you should use the update method - so to update the name of a product with a given ID, your code would look something like this:

```
export const updateProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const [productID, newProductName, userID] = [req.params.id, req.body.name, res.locals.user.id];
  const product = await prisma.product.update({
    where: {
      id: productID,
    },
    data: {
      name: newProductName
    }
  });
  res.status(200);
  res.json(product);
};
```

However, there's a problem here - I'm not checking to see that the product with the provided ID belongs to the user that has sent the request to update it. I have the ID of the user who has sent the request in the variable userID, and each product in the DB has a field belongsToID which is set to the ID of the user that the product belongs to. I should theoretically therefore be able to modify my query to get the product with the specified ID and a matching belongsToID like so:

```
export const updateProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const [productID, newProductName, userID] = [req.params.id, req.body.name, res.locals.user.id];
  const product = await prisma.product.update({
    where: {
      id: productID,
      belongsToID: userID
    },
    data: {
      name: newProductName
    }
  });
  res.status(200);
  res.json(product);
};
```

That, however, does not work - I get the following error: `Type '{ id: any; belongsToID: any; }' is not assignable to type 'ProductWhereUniqueInput'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'belongsToId' does not exist in type 'ProductWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2322)`.

It appears that when trying to do a 'findUnique', Prisma doesn't allow non-unique fields to be used in the query (even if the combination of both fields is unique, as is the case here). I do get that logically, my query doesn't make much sense - the ID alone is already enough to find a unique entry without the second field, so in that sense, the second field is totally redundant. Yet how else am I meant to check that the belongsToID is what it should be before updating the record? Is there somewhere else within the object passed to .update where I can provide a check to be performed on the retrieved record before performing the update?

I believe that creating an index would allow me to query for both fields at once - but why should I have to create an index when the ID (which is already indexed) alone is all I need to retrieve the record I need? What I really need is a way to perform a check on a retrieved record before performing the update when using `Prisma.table_name.update()`, not a way to query for something with a unique combination of fields.

Comment: Add the preview feature [extendedWhereUniqueInput](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-on-non-unique-fields-with-userwhereuniqueinput) to enable all fields on the model and not just unique fields in the `where` clause